# Setting up buttons in SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, sprite-kit

I'm discovering that `UIButtons` don't work very well with `SKScene`, So I'm attempting to subclass `SKNode` to make a button in `SpriteKit`.

The way I would like it to work is that if I initialize a button in `SKScene` and enable touch events, then the button will call a method in my `SKScene` when it is pressed.

I'd appreciate any advice that would lead me to finding the solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for more of a learning experience as well as a solution. I think the proper solution would be to set up the SKScene as a delegate of the button, but I'm unsure of how to do this. Can I set up the SKScene as an instance variable of the button and call a method of it?

Comment: You can do a number of things, delegation or more flexibly use NSNotification so any node can respond to it. If you use delegate make sure to set the delegate property to weak.

Comment: I've found [this code](https://github.com/sgerhardt/SpriteKitButton) to be helpful for creating sprite kit buttons. It extends SKSpriteKitNode and allows you to easily add text to buttons.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

you could use a SKSpriteNode as your button, and then when the user touches, check if that was the node touched. Use the SKSpriteNode's name property to identify the node:

```
//fire button
- (SKSpriteNode *)fireButtonNode
{
    SKSpriteNode *fireNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"fireButton.png"];
    fireNode.position = CGPointMake(fireButtonX,fireButtonY);
    fireNode.name = @"fireButtonNode";//how the node is identified later
    fireNode.zPosition = 1.0;
    return fireNode;
}
```

Add node to your scene:

```
[self addChild: [self fireButtonNode]];
```

Handle touches:

```
//handle touch events
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if fire button touched, bring the rain
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"fireButtonNode"]) {
         //do whatever...
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add an iVar as the button, you could remove the name checking and just use if ([_fireNode containsPoint:location]) does the same thing just different.

Comment: Comparing strings it's a dirty solution. Although @Smick 's solution is better, isn't there other cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: hey we can not add button in SpriteKit like SkLabelNode?

Comment: does this allow multi touch events? for example 2 buttons clicked simultaneously? one of them a movement button, another is a fire button.

Answer (score 52):

I've made my own Button-Class that I'm working with.
SKButton.h:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface SKButton : SKSpriteNode

@property (nonatomic, readonly) SEL actionTouchUpInside;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) SEL actionTouchDown;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) SEL actionTouchUp;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) id targetTouchUpInside;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) id targetTouchDown;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, weak) id targetTouchUp;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isEnabled;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, strong) SKLabelNode *title;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) SKTexture *normalTexture;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) SKTexture *selectedTexture;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) SKTexture *disabledTexture;

- (id)initWithTextureNormal:(SKTexture *)normal selected:(SKTexture *)selected;
- (id)initWithTextureNormal:(SKTexture *)normal selected:(SKTexture *)selected disabled:(SKTexture *)disabled; // Designated Initializer

- (id)initWithImageNamedNormal:(NSString *)normal selected:(NSString *)selected;
- (id)initWithImageNamedNormal:(NSString *)normal selected:(NSString *)selected disabled:(NSString *)disabled;

/** Sets the target-action pair, that is called when the Button is tapped.
 "target" won't be retained.
 */
- (void)setTouchUpInsideTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
- (void)setTouchDownTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;
- (void)setTouchUpTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action;

@end
```

SKButton.m:

```
#import "SKButton.h"
#import <objc/message.h>


@implementation SKButton

#pragma mark Texture Initializer

/**
 * Override the super-classes designated initializer, to get a properly set SKButton in every case
 */
- (id)initWithTexture:(SKTexture *)texture color:(UIColor *)color size:(CGSize)size {
    return [self initWithTextureNormal:texture selected:nil disabled:nil];
}

- (id)initWithTextureNormal:(SKTexture *)normal selected:(SKTexture *)selected {
    return [self initWithTextureNormal:normal selected:selected disabled:nil];
}

/**
 * This is the designated Initializer
 */
- (id)initWithTextureNormal:(SKTexture *)normal selected:(SKTexture *)selected disabled:(SKTexture *)disabled {
    self = [super initWithTexture:normal color:[UIColor whiteColor] size:normal.size];
    if (self) {
        [self setNormalTexture:normal];
        [self setSelectedTexture:selected];
        [self setDisabledTexture:disabled];
        [self setIsEnabled:YES];
        [self setIsSelected:NO];

        _title = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
        [_title setVerticalAlignmentMode:SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter];
        [_title setHorizontalAlignmentMode:SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter];

        [self addChild:_title];
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Image Initializer

- (id)initWithImageNamedNormal:(NSString *)normal selected:(NSString *)selected {
    return [self initWithImageNamedNormal:normal selected:selected disabled:nil];
}

- (id)initWithImageNamedNormal:(NSString *)normal selected:(NSString *)selected disabled:(NSString *)disabled {
    SKTexture *textureNormal = nil;
    if (normal) {
        textureNormal = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:normal];
    }

    SKTexture *textureSelected = nil;
    if (selected) {
        textureSelected = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:selected];
    }

    SKTexture *textureDisabled = nil;
    if (disabled) {
        textureDisabled = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:disabled];
    }

    return [self initWithTextureNormal:textureNormal selected:textureSelected disabled:textureDisabled];
}




#pragma -
#pragma mark Setting Target-Action pairs

- (void)setTouchUpInsideTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    _targetTouchUpInside = target;
    _actionTouchUpInside = action;
}

- (void)setTouchDownTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    _targetTouchDown = target;
    _actionTouchDown = action;
}

- (void)setTouchUpTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    _targetTouchUp = target;
    _actionTouchUp = action;
}

#pragma -
#pragma mark Setter overrides

- (void)setIsEnabled:(BOOL)isEnabled {
    _isEnabled = isEnabled;
    if ([self disabledTexture]) {
        if (!_isEnabled) {
            [self setTexture:_disabledTexture];
        } else {
            [self setTexture:_normalTexture];
        }
    }
}

- (void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)isSelected {
    _isSelected = isSelected;
    if ([self selectedTexture] && [self isEnabled]) {
        if (_isSelected) {
            [self setTexture:_selectedTexture];
        } else {
            [self setTexture:_normalTexture];
        }
    }
}

#pragma -
#pragma mark Touch Handling

/**
 * This method only occurs, if the touch was inside this node. Furthermore if 
 * the Button is enabled, the texture should change to "selectedTexture".
 */
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self isEnabled]) {
        objc_msgSend(_targetTouchDown, _actionTouchDown);
        [self setIsSelected:YES];
    }
}

/**
 * If the Button is enabled: This method looks, where the touch was moved to.
 * If the touch moves outside of the button, the isSelected property is restored
 * to NO and the texture changes to "normalTexture".
 */
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self isEnabled]) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint)) {
            [self setIsSelected:YES];
        } else {
            [self setIsSelected:NO];
        }
    }
}

/**
 * If the Button is enabled AND the touch ended in the buttons frame, the
 * selector of the target is run.
 */
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];

    if ([self isEnabled] && CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint)) {
        objc_msgSend(_targetTouchUpInside, _actionTouchUpInside);
    }
    [self setIsSelected:NO];
    objc_msgSend(_targetTouchUp, _actionTouchUp);
}
```

An example: To initialize a button, you write the following lines:

```
    SKButton *backButton = [[SKButton alloc] initWithImageNamedNormal:@"buttonNormal" selected:@"buttonSelected"];
    [backButton setPosition:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
    [backButton.title setText:@"Button"];
    [backButton.title setFontName:@"Chalkduster"];
    [backButton.title setFontSize:20.0];
    [backButton setTouchUpInsideTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction)];
    [self addChild:backButton];
```

Furthermore you need the 'buttonAction' method in your class.
*** No warranty that this class is working right in every case. I'm still quite new to objective-c. ***

If you think having to do this is annoying and pointless you can disable the check in the build settings by setting 'Enable strict checking of `objc_msgSend Calls'` to '`No`'

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Is there a reason why you use `objc_msgSend` instead of `[target performSelector:selector]`?

Comment: Ah yes, darn ARC. I forgot about that warning :| Here's a nice work around if you're interested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895287/performselector-arc-warning

Comment: The above code is great, but I'm getting errors when trying to use 
- (void)changeToScene:(SKButtonNode *)sender {} as the @selector. I'd rather use a single method to switch scenes by using sender.name if I could.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I'm including it in my code. We'll see if it works. One suggestion: change the name of the class from SKButton to something more unique to you e.g., GRFButton. At some point, Apple may introduce an SKButton and you don't want to confuse the namespace and break your code later on.

Comment: @BeauYoung - It works when you add the `self` at the end like so: `objc_msgSend(_targetTouchUpInside, _actionTouchUpInside, self)`

Comment: @Gomfucius That's amazing! Saved me heaps of trouble. Still quite new to using messages. Why would this have been left out in the first place?

Comment: @BeauYoung - I'm not sure, that would be a question for Graf.

Comment: how do i add the buttonAction method?

Comment: This should be cocoapod-ified or at least put on github.

Comment: This code is throwing an error in xcode6 in regard to the use of objc_msgSend. See here for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922913/too-many-arguments-to-function-call-expected-0-have-3

Comment: With iOS 8, using "normalTexture" will cause a conflict. To resolve this, you will need to rename "normalTexture" to something such as "myNormalTexture". This is a great little class btw, thanks for sharing!

Reference this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670506/xcode-does-not-synthesize-property-with-ios-8-sdk

Answer (score 20):

For people writing their games in Swift!
I have rewritten the essential parts of Graf's solution to a swift class. Hope it helps:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class FTButtonNode: SKSpriteNode {

    enum FTButtonActionType: Int {
        case TouchUpInside = 1,
        TouchDown, TouchUp
    }

    var isEnabled: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        if (disabledTexture != nil) {
            texture = isEnabled ? defaultTexture : disabledTexture
        }
    }
    }
    var isSelected: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        texture = isSelected ? selectedTexture : defaultTexture
    }
    }
    var defaultTexture: SKTexture
    var selectedTexture: SKTexture

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    init(normalTexture defaultTexture: SKTexture!, selectedTexture:SKTexture!, disabledTexture: SKTexture?) {

        self.defaultTexture = defaultTexture
        self.selectedTexture = selectedTexture
        self.disabledTexture = disabledTexture

        super.init(texture: defaultTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: defaultTexture.size())

        userInteractionEnabled = true

        // Adding this node as an empty layer. Without it the touch functions are not being called
        // The reason for this is unknown when this was implemented...?
        let bugFixLayerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: nil, size: defaultTexture.size())
        bugFixLayerNode.position = self.position
        addChild(bugFixLayerNode)

    }

    /**
    * Taking a target object and adding an action that is triggered by a button event.
    */
    func setButtonAction(target: AnyObject, triggerEvent event:FTButtonActionType, action:Selector) {

        switch (event) {
        case .TouchUpInside:
            targetTouchUpInside = target
            actionTouchUpInside = action
        case .TouchDown:
            targetTouchDown = target
            actionTouchDown = action
        case .TouchUp:
            targetTouchUp = target
            actionTouchUp = action
        }

    }

    var disabledTexture: SKTexture?
    var actionTouchUpInside: Selector?
    var actionTouchUp: Selector?
    var actionTouchDown: Selector?
    weak var targetTouchUpInside: AnyObject?
    weak var targetTouchUp: AnyObject?
    weak var targetTouchDown: AnyObject?

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)  {
        let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }
        isSelected = true
        if (targetTouchDown != nil && targetTouchDown!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchDown!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchDown!, to: targetTouchDown, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }


    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)  {

        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }

        let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation)) {
            isSelected = true
        } else {
            isSelected = false
        }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }

        isSelected = false

        if (targetTouchUpInside != nil && targetTouchUpInside!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUpInside!)) {
            let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation) ) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUpInside!, to: targetTouchUpInside, from: self, forEvent: nil)
            }

        }

        if (targetTouchUp != nil && targetTouchUp!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUp!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUp!, to: targetTouchUp, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you desire, you **can** use UIButton (or any other UIView).

When a `SKScene` is created, it doesn't yet exist in an `SKView`. You should implement `didMoveToView:` on your `SKScene` subclass. At this point, you have access to the `SKView` the scene is placed in and you can add `UIKit` objects to it.  For prettiness, I faded them in …

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
  UIView *b = [self _createButton];  // <-- performs [self.view addSubview:button]
  // create other UI elements, also add them to the list to remove …
  self.customSubviews = @[b];

  b.alpha = 0;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                        delay:2.4
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                   animations:^{
                     b.alpha = 1;
                   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     ;
                   }];
}
```

you will need to deliberately remove them from the scene when you transition away, unless of course it makes total sense for them to remain there.

```
- (void)removeCustomSubviews {
  for (UIView *v in self.customSubviews) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                       v.alpha = 0;
                   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                       [v removeFromSuperview];
                 }];
  }
}
```

---

For those unfamiliar with programmatically creating a `UIButton`, here one example (you could do a 100 things differently here) …

```
- (UIButton *)_createButton {
  UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [b setTitle:@"Continue" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [b setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [b setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenButtonSelected"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
  b.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
  b.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:36];
  b.frame = CGRectMake(self.size.width * .7, self.size.height * .2, self.size.width * .2, self.size.height * .1);
  [b addTarget:self action:@selector(continuePlay) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view addSubview:b];

  return b;
}
```

Reminder: `UIView` origin is in the upper left, `SKScene` origin is in the lower left.

Answer (score 3):

I have used SKButton class by [Graf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2724767/graf).

I use the SKButton to do scene navigation.  i.e present another scene when the user press the SKButton.  I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error at `touchesEnded->[self setIsSelected:NO]`.  This happens especially frequently on the latest iPad with fast CPU.

After checking and troubleshooting, I realised that the SKButton object is already "deallocated" when the `setIsSelected` function is being called.  This is because I use the SKButton to navigate to next scene and this also means that the current scene can be deallocated any time.

I made a small change by putting the setIsSelected in the "else" portion as follows.

Hope this helps for other developer who also see the same error.

```
(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];

    if ([self isEnabled] && CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint)) {
        objc_msgSend(_targetTouchUpInside, _actionTouchUpInside);
    } else {
       [self setIsSelected:NO];
    }
    objc_msgSend(_targetTouchUp, _actionTouchUp);
}
```

Comment: Please format your post & sourcecode, it is very hard to read this way!

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I've made a github repo for my SKButtonNode that I'll hopefully be keeping current and updating as swift evolves!

[SKButtonNode](https://github.com/morganwesemann/SKButtonNode)

---

Unfortunately I cannot comment yet on Filip's swift implementation of SKButton in Swift. Super happy that he made this in Swift! But, I noticed that he didn't include a function to add text to the button. This is a huge feature to me, so that you don't have to create separate assets for every single button, rather just the background and add dynamic text.

I added a simple function to add a text label to SKButton. It likely isn't perfect--I'm new to Swift just like everyone else! Feel free to comment and help me update this to the best it can be. Hope you guys like!

```
 //Define label with the textures
 var defaultTexture: SKTexture
 var selectedTexture: SKTexture

 //New defining of label
 var label: SKLabelNode

 //Updated init() function:

 init(normalTexture defaultTexture: SKTexture!, selectedTexture:SKTexture!, disabledTexture: SKTexture?) {

    self.defaultTexture = defaultTexture
    self.selectedTexture = selectedTexture
    self.disabledTexture = disabledTexture

    //New initialization of label
    self.label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica");

    super.init(texture: defaultTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: defaultTexture.size())
    userInteractionEnabled = true

    //Creating and adding a blank label, centered on the button
    self.label.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Center;
    self.label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center;
    addChild(self.label)

    // Adding this node as an empty layer. Without it the touch functions are not being called
    // The reason for this is unknown when this was implemented...?
    let bugFixLayerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: nil, size: defaultTexture.size())
    bugFixLayerNode.position = self.position
    addChild(bugFixLayerNode)

  }




    /*
      New function for setting text. Calling function multiple times does 
      not create a ton of new labels, just updates existing label.
      You can set the title, font type and font size with this function
    */

    func setButtonLabel(#title: NSString, font: String, fontSize: CGFloat) {
        var title = title
        var font = font
        var fontSize = fontSize

        self.label.text = title
        self.label.fontSize = fontSize
        self.label.fontName = font        
     }
```

Sample creation of button:

```
    var buttonTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Button");
    var buttonPressedTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Button Pressed");
    var button = SKButton(normalTexture:buttonTexture, selectedTexture:buttonPressedTexture, disabledTexture:buttonPressedTexture);
    button.setButtonLabel(title: "Play",font: "Helvetica",fontSize: 40);
    button.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
    self.addChild(button);
```

Full Class Listed Below:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit


class SKButton: SKSpriteNode {




enum FTButtonActionType: Int {
    case TouchUpInside = 1,
    TouchDown, TouchUp
}

var isEnabled: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        if (disabledTexture != nil) {
            texture = isEnabled ? defaultTexture : disabledTexture
        }
    }
}
var isSelected: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        texture = isSelected ? selectedTexture : defaultTexture
    }
}
var defaultTexture: SKTexture
var selectedTexture: SKTexture
var label: SKLabelNode


required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}

init(normalTexture defaultTexture: SKTexture!, selectedTexture:SKTexture!, disabledTexture: SKTexture?) {

    self.defaultTexture = defaultTexture
    self.selectedTexture = selectedTexture
    self.disabledTexture = disabledTexture
    self.label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica");
    super.init(texture: defaultTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: defaultTexture.size())
    userInteractionEnabled = true


    self.label.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Center;
    self.label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center;
    addChild(self.label)

    // Adding this node as an empty layer. Without it the touch functions are not being called
    // The reason for this is unknown when this was implemented...?
    let bugFixLayerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: nil, size: defaultTexture.size())
    bugFixLayerNode.position = self.position
    addChild(bugFixLayerNode)

}

/**
* Taking a target object and adding an action that is triggered by a button event.
*/
func setButtonAction(target: AnyObject, triggerEvent event:FTButtonActionType, action:Selector) {

    switch (event) {
    case .TouchUpInside:
        targetTouchUpInside = target
        actionTouchUpInside = action
    case .TouchDown:
        targetTouchDown = target
        actionTouchDown = action
    case .TouchUp:
        targetTouchUp = target
        actionTouchUp = action
    }

}


func setButtonLabel(#title: NSString, font: String, fontSize: CGFloat) {
    var title = title;
    var font = font;
    var fontSize = fontSize;

    self.label.text = title;
    self.label.fontSize = fontSize;
    self.label.fontName = font;

}

var disabledTexture: SKTexture?
var actionTouchUpInside: Selector?
var actionTouchUp: Selector?
var actionTouchDown: Selector?
weak var targetTouchUpInside: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchUp: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchDown: AnyObject?

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)  {
    let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

    if (!isEnabled) {
        return
    }
    isSelected = true
    if (targetTouchDown != nil && targetTouchDown!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchDown!)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchDown!, to: targetTouchDown, from: self, forEvent: nil)
    }


}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)  {

    if (!isEnabled) {
        return
    }

    let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation)) {
        isSelected = true
    } else {
        isSelected = false
    }

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    if (!isEnabled) {
        return
    }

    isSelected = false

    if (targetTouchUpInside != nil && targetTouchUpInside!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUpInside!)) {
        let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation) ) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUpInside!, to: targetTouchUpInside, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }

    }

    if (targetTouchUp != nil && targetTouchUp!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUp!)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUp!, to: targetTouchUp, from: self, forEvent: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Updated the code for swift 2.1 here: https://gist.github.com/richy486/5d408c442ac1c0c2891f

Comment: ..and I updated to Swift 3 here: https://github.com/jglasse/SKButtonSwift3

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version based on Filip's Swift code. I've just simplified it a little and allowed it to take blocks rather than only selectors :

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

enum FTButtonTarget {
    case aSelector(Selector, AnyObject)
    case aBlock(() -> Void)
}

class FTButtonNode: SKSpriteNode {

    var actionTouchUp : FTButtonTarget?
    var actionTouchUpInside : FTButtonTarget?
    var actionTouchDown : FTButtonTarget?

    var isEnabled: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if (disabledTexture != nil) {
                texture = isEnabled ? defaultTexture : disabledTexture
            }
        }
    }
    var isSelected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            texture = isSelected ? selectedTexture : defaultTexture
        }
    }

    var defaultTexture: SKTexture
    var selectedTexture: SKTexture

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

init(normalTexture defaultTexture: SKTexture!, selectedTexture:SKTexture!, disabledTexture: SKTexture?) {

    self.defaultTexture = defaultTexture
    self.selectedTexture = selectedTexture
    self.disabledTexture = disabledTexture

    super.init(texture: defaultTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: defaultTexture.size())

    userInteractionEnabled = true

    // Adding this node as an empty layer. Without it the touch functions are not being called
    // The reason for this is unknown when this was implemented...?
    let bugFixLayerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: nil, size: defaultTexture.size())
    bugFixLayerNode.position = self.position
    addChild(bugFixLayerNode)

}

var disabledTexture: SKTexture?

func callTarget(buttonTarget:FTButtonTarget) {

    switch buttonTarget {
    case let .aSelector(selector, target):
        if target.respondsToSelector(selector) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(selector, to: target, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }
    case let .aBlock(block):
        block()
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)  {
    let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

    if (!isEnabled) {
        return
    }
    isSelected = true

    if let act = actionTouchDown {
        callTarget(act)
    }

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)  {

    if (!isEnabled) {
        return
    }

    let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation)) {
        isSelected = true
    } else {
        isSelected = false
    }

}

 override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

     if (!isEnabled) {
         return
     }

     isSelected = false

     let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
     let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

     if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation) ) {

         if let act = actionTouchUpInside {
             callTarget(act)
         }
     }

     if let act = actionTouchUp {
         callTarget(act)
     }
 }
}
```

Use it like this :

```
       aFTButton.actionTouchUpInside = FTButtonTarget.aBlock({ () -> Void in
        println("button touched")
    })
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

What a lot of great solutions to this problem! For the hardcore scrollers that make it down this far, you're in for a treat!  I have subclassed `SKScene`, and it takes ONE function call to register ANY node to act like a `UIButton`!  Here is the class:

```
class KCScene : SKScene {
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//This function is the only thing you use in this class!!!
func addButton(_ node:SKNode, withCompletionHandler handler: @escaping ()->()) {
    let data = ButtonData(button: node, actionToPerform: handler)
    eligibleButtons.append(data)
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private struct ButtonData {
    //TODO: make a dictionary with ()->() as the value and SKNode as the key.
    //Then refactor this class!
    let button:SKNode
    let actionToPerform:()->()
}

private struct TouchTrackingData {
    //this will be in a dictionary with a UITouch object as the key
    let button:SKNode
    let originalButtonFrame:CGRect
}

private var eligibleButtons = [ButtonData]()
private var trackedTouches = [UITouch:TouchTrackingData]()
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//TODO: make these functions customizable,
//with these implementations as defaults.
private func applyTouchedDownEffectToNode(node:SKNode) {
    node.alpha  = 0.5
    node.xScale = 0.8
    node.yScale = 0.8
}
private func applyTouchedUpEffectToNode(node:SKNode)   {
    node.alpha  = 1
    node.xScale = 1
    node.yScale = 1
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        let touchedNode = atPoint(touchLocation)

        for buttonData in eligibleButtons {
            if touchedNode === buttonData.button {
                //then this touch needs to be tracked, as it touched down on an eligible button!
                for (t, bD) in trackedTouches {
                    if bD.button === buttonData.button {
                        //then this button was already being tracked by a previous touch, disable the previous touch
                        trackedTouches[t] = nil
                    }
                }
                //start tracking this touch
                trackedTouches[touch] = TouchTrackingData(button: touchedNode, originalButtonFrame: touchedNode.frameInScene)
                applyTouchedDownEffectToNode(node: buttonData.button)
            }
        }
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        if trackedTouches[touch] == nil {continue}
        //Now we know this touch is being tracked...
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)
        //TODO: implement an isBeingTouched property on TouchTrackingData, so 
        //applyTouchedDown(Up)Effect doesn't have to be called EVERY move the touch makes
        if trackedTouches[touch]!.originalButtonFrame.contains(touchLocation) {
            //if this tracked touch is touching its button
            applyTouchedDownEffectToNode(node: trackedTouches[touch]!.button)
        } else {
            applyTouchedUpEffectToNode(node: trackedTouches[touch]!.button)
        }

    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        if trackedTouches[touch] == nil {continue}
        //Now we know this touch is being tracked...
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

        if trackedTouches[touch]!.originalButtonFrame.contains(touchLocation) {
            applyTouchedUpEffectToNode(node: trackedTouches[touch]!.button)

            for buttonData in eligibleButtons {
                if buttonData.button === trackedTouches[touch]!.button {
                    buttonData.actionToPerform()
                }
            }
        }
        trackedTouches[touch] = nil
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>?, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches! {
        if trackedTouches[touch] == nil {continue}
        //Now we know this touch is being tracked...
        //Since this touch was cancelled, it will not be activating a button,
        //and it is not worth checking where the touch was
        //we will simply apply the touched up effect regardless and remove the touch from being tracked
        applyTouchedUpEffectToNode(node: trackedTouches[touch]!.button)
        trackedTouches[touch] = nil
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

}

It includes a lot of ideas I haven't yet implemented and some explanations of the code, but just copy and paste it into your project, and you can use it as-is in your own scene.  Here is a complete example usage:

```
class GameScene : KCScene {
var playButton:SKSpriteNode
override init(size:CGSize) {
    playButton = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width:200,height:200))
    playButton.position.x = size.width/2
    playButton.position.y = size.height*0.75
    super.init(size: size)
}
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addChild(playButton)
    addButton(playButton, withCompletionHandler: playButtonPushed)
}
func playButtonPushed() {
    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 768, height: 1024))
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    view!.presentScene(scene)
}
}
```

The one caveat, is if you implement `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, and/or `touchesCancelled` you MUST CALL SUPER!  Or else it will not work.

And please realize that in that example, there is really only ONE LINE OF CODE you need to give ANY NODE `UIButton` characteristics!  It was this line:

```
addButton(playButton, withCompletionHandler: playButtonPushed)
```

I'm always open for ideas and suggestions.  Leave 'em in the comments and Happy Coding!!

Oops, I forgot to mention I use this nifty extension.  You can take it out of an extension (as you probably don't need it in every node) and plop it in my class.  I only use it in one place.

```
extension SKNode {
var frameInScene:CGRect {
    if let scene = scene, let parent = parent {
        let rectOriginInScene = scene.convert(frame.origin, from: parent)
        return CGRect(origin: rectOriginInScene, size: frame.size)
    }
    return frame
}
```

}

Comment: How does this ensure that the playButtonPushed completion function is accessible? Or where do I put the playButtonPushed function to ensure it's reachable by the KScene instance, which I assume is the button?

Comment: @Confused You would make your own scene a subclass of KCScene instead of SKScene: `class ConfusedScene : KCScene {`. Then inside `ConfusedScene` just make a function to do what you want when the button is pressed.  I did this: `func playButtonPushed() { /*do whatever happens when play button is pushed*/}`.  Why this works is too involved to explain here, but you can read about closures [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94).

Answer (score 1):

My solution to solve this problem written completely in SWIFT, using closures.

Its pretty simple to use! https://github.com/txaidw/TWControls

```
class Test {
    var testProperty = "Default String"

    init() {
        let control = TWButton(normalColor: SKColor.blueColor(), highlightedColor: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 160, height: 80))
        control.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        control.position.allStatesLabelText = "PLAY"
        control.addClosureFor(.TouchUpInside, target: self, closure: { (scene, sender) -> () in
            scene.testProperty = "Changed Property"
        })
    }

    deinit { println("Class Released..") }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple button written with modern Swift (4.1.2)

Features

- it accepts 2 image names, 1 for the default state and one for the active state
- the developer can set the `touchBeganCallback` and `touchEndedCallback` closures to add custom behaviour

### Code

```
import SpriteKit

class SpriteKitButton: SKSpriteNode {

    private let textureDefault: SKTexture
    private let textureActive: SKTexture

    init(defaultImageNamed: String, activeImageNamed:String) {
        textureDefault = SKTexture(imageNamed: defaultImageNamed)
        textureActive = SKTexture(imageNamed: activeImageNamed)
        super.init(texture: textureDefault, color: .clear, size: textureDefault.size())
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }

    var touchBeganCallback: (() -> Void)?
    var touchEndedCallback: (() -> Void)?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.texture = textureActive
        touchBeganCallback?()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.texture = textureDefault
        touchEndedCallback?()
    }
}
```

### How to use it

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // 1. create the button
        let button = SpriteKitButton(defaultImageNamed: "default", activeImageNamed: "active")

        // 2. write what should happen when the button is tapped
        button.touchBeganCallback = {
            print("Touch began")
        }

        // 3. write what should happen when the button is released
        button.touchEndedCallback = {
            print("Touch ended")
        }

        // 4. add the button to the scene
        addChild(button)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had created a class for using SKSpriteNode as a button quite a while ago. You can find it on GitHub here.

[**AGSpriteButton**](https://github.com/akashgupta88/AGSpriteButton)

It's implementation is based on UIButton, so if you are already familiar with iOS, you should find it easy to work with.

It can also be assigned a block or an SKAction to be executed when the button is pressed.

It includes a method to set up a label as well.

A button will typically be declared like so:

```
AGSpriteButton *button = [AGSpriteButton buttonWithColor:[UIColor redColor] andSize:CGSizeMake(300, 100)];
[button setLabelWithText:@"Button Text" andFont:nil withColor:nil];
button.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 3);
[button addTarget:self selector:@selector(someSelector) withObject:nil forControlEvent:AGButtonControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addChild:button];
```

And that's it. You're good to go.

Comment: Is there any reason we couldn't use SKColor instead of UIColor? If we use UIColor we're stuck on iOS.

Comment: You can as easily use SKColor instead of UIColor

Answer (score 0):

And since all of us aren't targeting iOS, here's the start of some code I wrote to handle mouse interaction on the Mac.

Question for the gurus: does MacOS offer touch events when using a trackpad? Or are these sent into SpriteKit as mouse events?

Another question for the gurus, shouldn't this class properly be called SKButton**Node**?

Anyway, try this...

```
#if os(iOS)
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)  {
        let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

        if (!isEnabled) { return }

        isSelected = true
        if (targetTouchDown != nil && targetTouchDown!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchDown!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchDown!, to: targetTouchDown, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)  {
        if (!isEnabled) { return }

        let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation)) {
            isSelected = true
        } else {
            isSelected = false
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        if (!isEnabled) { return }

        isSelected = false

        if (targetTouchUpInside != nil && targetTouchUpInside!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUpInside!)) {
            let touch: AnyObject! = touches.anyObject()
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent)

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation) ) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUpInside!, to: targetTouchUpInside, from: self, forEvent: nil)
            }
        }

        if (targetTouchUp != nil && targetTouchUp!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUp!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUp!, to: targetTouchUp, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }
    }
#else

    // FIXME: needs support for mouse enter and leave, turning on and off selection

    override func mouseDown(event: NSEvent) {
        if (!isEnabled) { return }

        if (targetTouchDown != nil && targetTouchDown!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchDown!)) {
            NSApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchDown!, to: targetTouchDown, from: self)
        }
    }

    override func mouseUp(event: NSEvent) {
        if (!isEnabled) { return }

        if (targetTouchUpInside != nil && targetTouchUpInside!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUpInside!)) {
            let touchLocation = event.locationInNode(parent)

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation) ) {
                NSApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUpInside!, to: targetTouchUpInside, from: self)
            }
        }

        if (targetTouchUp != nil && targetTouchUp!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUp!)) {
            NSApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUp!, to: targetTouchUp, from: self)
        }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: As far as I know Spritekit for OSX only observes mouse stuff :/  And yeah, it probably should have the word Node on the end. Like SKLabelNode.

Answer (score 0):

I have subclassed `SKScene` class and achieved the problem of solving button taps in this project.

https://github.com/Prasad9/SpriteKitButton

In it, all the nodes which are necessary to be known upon tapped should be named.

In addition to detecting button tap, this project also enables you to detect whether the touch on a particular node has started or ended.

To get tap action, override the following method in your Scene file.

```
- (void)touchUpInsideOnNodeName:(NSString *)nodeName atPoint:(CGPoint)touchPoint {
    // Your code here.
 }
```

To get to know the start of touch on a particular body, override the following method in your Scene file.

```
 - (void)touchBeginOnNodeName:(NSString *)nodeName {
    // Your code here.
 }
```

To get to know the end of touch on a particular body, override the following method in your Scene file.

```
 - (void)touchEndedOnNodeName:(NSString *)nodeName {
    // Your code here.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Graf`s solution has one issue. 
For example:

```
self.pauseButton = [[AGSKBButtonNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"ButtonPause"];
self.pauseButton.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[self.pauseButton setTouchUpInsideTarget:self action:@selector(pauseButtonPressed)];

[_hudLayer addChild:_pauseButton];
```

_hudLayer is a SKNode, a property of my scene. So, you`ll get exception, because of method touchesEnded in SKButton. It will call [SKSpriteNode pauseButtonPressed], not with scene.

The solution to change self.parent to touch target:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInNode:self.parent];

if ([self isEnabled] && CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, touchPoint)) {
    if (_actionTouchUpInside){
        [_targetTouchUpInside performSelectorOnMainThread:_actionTouchUpInside withObject:_targetTouchUpInside waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
}
[self setIsSelected:NO];
if (_actionTouchUp){
    [_targetTouchUp performSelectorOnMainThread:_actionTouchUp withObject:_targetTouchUp waitUntilDone:YES];
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually this work well on **Swift 2.2** on **Xcode 7.3**

I like **FTButtonNode**  ([richy486/FTButtonNode.swift](https://gist.github.com/richy486/5d408c442ac1c0c2891f)
) but it's not possible to specify another size (rather then default texture size) directly during initialization so I've added this simple method:

You must copy that under the official custom init method (similar to this) so you have another init method to use:

```
init(normalTexture defaultTexture: SKTexture!, selectedTexture:SKTexture!, disabledTexture: SKTexture?, size:CGSize) {

        self.defaultTexture = defaultTexture
        self.selectedTexture = selectedTexture
        self.disabledTexture = disabledTexture
        self.label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica");

        super.init(texture: defaultTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: size)
        userInteractionEnabled = true

        //Creating and adding a blank label, centered on the button
        self.label.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Center;
        self.label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center;
        addChild(self.label)

        // Adding this node as an empty layer. Without it the touch functions are not being called
        // The reason for this is unknown when this was implemented...?
        let bugFixLayerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: size)
        bugFixLayerNode.position = self.position
        addChild(bugFixLayerNode)

    }
```

Another important thing is the "selection time", I've seen that in the new devices (iPhone 6) sometime the time between `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` is too fast and you dont see the changes between `defaultTexture` and `selectedTexture`.

With this function:

```
func dispatchDelay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

you can re-write the `touchesEnded` method to show correctly the texture variation:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }

        dispatchDelay(0.2) {
            self.isSelected = false
        }

        if (targetTouchUpInside != nil && targetTouchUpInside!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUpInside!)) {
            let touch: AnyObject! = touches.first
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent!)

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation) ) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUpInside!, to: targetTouchUpInside, from: self, forEvent: nil)
            }

        }

        if (targetTouchUp != nil && targetTouchUp!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUp!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUp!, to: targetTouchUp, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't convinced of any of the above options, so based on the latest Swift4 I created [my own solution](https://gist.github.com/Bersaelor/dce900a03942c5a7fc0a3c5919f3fc13).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SpriteKit does not have button node, I do not know why, because it is very useful control. So I decided to create my own and share via CocoaPods, please use it [OOButtonNode](https://github.com/ooleynich/OOButtonNode).
Buttons can use text/background or images, written in Swift 4.