# Setting up a game menu using Spritekit

Tags: iphone, ios7, sprite-kit

Okay i need the best possible way to achieve an `ingame menu` in my game . I'm using `spritekit`, i was thinking of making an uiview with its nib file and then add that to my scene but then it being an uiview and my area of implementation being a `skscene` i won't be able to relate them  so what other ways can i implement it?

Is it possible to setup a new `spritenode` to act as the game menu and then add buttons and labels into it? and then add it to my scene whenever i need it?? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: yes, detect touches on a sprite but uibutton etc would also work

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can nest SKSPriteNodes just like views to create a menu layout.  Here is an SKButton class you can use [(SKButton)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19199748/2526115) to create the buttons.