# Adding a UIButton to a SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, sprite-kit, skscene

What is the best way to add a `UIButton` to an `SKScene`?

I realize that I probably can't add it as a subview of the scene, so what is the alternative so that I can have a tappable button on top of a scene?

Comment: Refer to the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/spritekit-setting-up-buttons-in-skscene

Comment: UIKit views are (can only be) added to the SKView, not the scene or other nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt for one of the following ways:

1 - Subclass SKSpriteNode to act as a button

2 - Implement touch delegates within the scene and respond if your 'button' node is touched

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/spritekit-setting-up-buttons-in-skscene) will tell u how to implement the two above.

3 - Use a component like the SpriteKit Button which can be found [here](https://github.com/sgerhardt/SpriteKitButton).

Comment: I think that #2 is the best solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 /// create a uibutton in skscene (spritkit)

      UIButton * startButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 60, 20)];
                startButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

                [self.view addSubview:startButton];

/// if u want to connect it to a method or function /// 

[startButton addTarget:self action:@selector(StartBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```