# Creating a custom slider using Sprite Kit - how do I pass a @selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, sprite-kit

A Sprite Kit game I'm working on uses a custom slider to act as a color picker (the color is picked from the slider track graphic, which is a `UIImage` containing a gradient).

I looked into using a customised `UISlider`, but standard IOS UI controls don't play well with Sprite Kit's Scenes: they're difficult to position relative to the rest of the Scene (as they exist as a subview of the main View rather than as a part of a `SKScene`), they pop into existence (rather than transitioning with the rest of the Scene) and must be manually removed when exiting the scene. In short, implementing them is a pain, and they don't integrate seamlessly.

I've started implementing a custom slider using `SKSpriteNode`s, building on [Graf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2724767/graf)'s [excellent SKButton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/spritekit-setting-up-buttons-in-skscene/19199748#19199748), and have the slider track and handle in place. The handle is sliding left and right along the track, and is setting a value between 0 and 1 (just like a `UISlider`). I've called this class `SKSlider`.

What I would like to do is pass the `SKSlider` a `@selector`, in much the same way as you would  a `UISlider`, so I can define a function inside the `SKScene` for the slider to execute:

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

The function I'm trying to invoke when the slider's changed looks like this:

```
-(UIColor*)getRGBAFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(float)xp atY:(float)yp
{
    NSMutableArray *resultColor = [NSMutableArray array];   
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));

    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);



    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.

    int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yp) + xp * bytesPerPixel;
    CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) /255.0;
    CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0)/255.0 ;
    CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0)/255.0 ;
    CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) /255.0;

    byteIndex += 4;

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];

    [resultColor addObject:color];

    NSLog(@"width:%i hight:%i Color:%@",width,height,[color description]);

    free(rawData);

    return color;        
}
```

(Code was found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gangeshwardev/ios-library/get-pixel-rgb-or-uicolor-data-from-a-uiimage-or-cgimage-on-cgpoint), for those interested.)

But I'm not sure how I should set this up in the `SKSlider`'s interface. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement the missing method in your custom slider. Add this in the interface:

```
- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

And in implementation store `target` and `action` as a properties.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id target;
@property (nonatomic) SEL action;

- (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
{
    _target = target;
    _action = action;
}
```

Then call an `action` on a `target` when value changes:

```
objc_msgSend(_target, _action);
```

Remember to import:

```
#import <objc/message.h>
```

Then to get the updates from the slider create a `valueChanged` method and add it:

```
- (void)valueChanged
{
    CGFloat value = _yourSlider.value;
    // Do something with the value.
}

[_yourSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Comment: Hmm, getting there I think... but it's coming up with errors now: `Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'SEL' (aka 'SEL *') is disallowed with ARC` and `PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown`...

Comment: I'm still getting the ARC restrictions warning saying Implicit conversion is disallowed :(

Comment: Very nearly there, I think! From what I understand, I call it like: `[skinSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(getRGBAFromImage:atX:atY:)
               withObject:skinGradient
               withObject: skinSlider.value
               withObject: 0
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];` (to pass in the variables), so how should I change the interface?

Comment: Don't put the logic that should not be in the slider into it. Slider is a control. It should just do its sliding and inform the target about it. Then, the target object (probably your view controller or scene) should handle the value and do something with it. I updated my answer.

Comment: Fantastic. That works brilliantly and you've informed me on a bunch of new things. A thousand thank yous, upvotes, accepts etc.

Answer (score 2):

The variable type for a selector is `SEL`.  Here's how you would declare properties to keep track of the target and action.  (Note that `SEL` is a pointer to a structure, not a pointer to an object, so specifying `strong` or `weak` will upset the compiler.)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id target;
@property (nonatomic) SEL action;
```

Here's a sample method that updates the target and action

```
- (void)changeTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    self.target = target;
    self.action = action;
}
```

And this is how you call the action method on the target

```
[self.target performSelector:self.action withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];
```

Note that self is passed as an argument to the method, so the method signature in the target should be

```
- (void)someAction:(id)sender
```

Comment: reecon beat you to it (just), but your answer's useful, too: upvoted.