# How to implement target/action in Swift?

Tags: ios, oop, model-view-controller, notifications, key-value-observing

I am trying to build a custom slider using `SpriteKit`.

The `Scrubber : SKScene` class is responsible for creating the **slider**. 
The `viewDidLoad` in my `ViewController` looks like this

```
       var scrubber : Scrubber!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 // Create the scrubber 

    if let view = self.spriteView {
        if let scene = Scrubber(fileNamed: "Scrubber") {
            self.scrubber = scene
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene) }

               } }
```

It has a *thumb* sliding left and right along a *track*, and is setting a value between 0 and 1  and I would like to implement the

```
addTarget(_:action:for: .valueChanged)          // just like a UISlider
```

Every time the the *thumb* slides left or right OR *jumps* to a `position.X` the , `value` changes.

I want to call a method in my `ViewController` class everytime the `value` changes.

How can I do this?

**NOTE:**

- This question has previously been asked   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220079/creating-a-custom-slider-using-sprite-kit-how-do-i-pass-a-selector) , but it is in **Objective-C** , and I couldn't get the solution to work for swift.
- There is no `UIControlEvent` in my case .The `valueChanged(..)` event has to be set up in code explicitly. What I want to know is , how can a `target/Action` scheme be used in the absence of a `UIControl`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hooking up UIButton to closure? (Swift, target-action)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962151/hooking-up-uibutton-to-closure-swift-target-action)

Comment: My use case  is, how to create a _target / action_ scheme , when there is no `UIControlEvent` involved