# Changing size of SKSpritenode rectangle frame

Tags: ios, size, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a SKSpritenode that has an initial size of (20,100).
If I rotate the node, then the framesize changes.
For example if I rotate the node by 45°, then the framesize is (50,70).
So after rotation, the frame is bigger than the texture of the node.
And the problem is, that i select the node by clicking the frame, but i only want to select it, when i click on the texture.

I use this code to select my node.

```
    CGPoint eachTouchLocation = [eachTouch locationInNode:self];
    NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:eachTouchLocation];
```

Comment: "... if i tap on the frame, which is part of the frame, but not part of the picture...". You need to clarify your question!

Comment: i would love to upload a picture, but i can't -.-". What i mean is that the frame of the node is bigger than the texture of the node when i rotate the node and i can select the node by just clicking on the frame, but i only want to select the node, when i click on the texture.

Comment: This is a similar question. Ivan Lesko's comments point to a solution for your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261874/changing-skspritenode-frame-isometric-challenges