# call "touches-cancelled" method in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, touchescancelled

I add a button as spriteNode to a scene, and i want to run an action when the touch cancelled.

I add a "touches-cancelled" method and write an "NSLog" to test if this method is called. After I run my project, there is no output showing this method is called.

how can i run the "touches cancelled" method to my button?

Comment: Touch cancelled is only called when something unexpected happened (like a phone call). Try to overwrite `touchesEnded:`

Comment: Do you want to call a method when the button is touched? OR when the button press is cancelled OR when overall touches are cancelled?

Comment: I call a method which changes the image of the button when user clicks the button. I want another method to change the image back to the previous one when the user moves finger out of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to effectively implement something like touchesCancelled on a button node based on the touchPosition, you will need to subclass SKSpriteNode to act as a button. It will have to implement the touch delegates on it's own.

A sample of how to do this can be found in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19199748/2043580

It includes code which sets the texture back to the unselected state when the touchPoint goes out of the node's bounds in the `-touchesMoved` method.