# is it a good practice to use Storyboard and Spritekit to make a game in IOS?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, storyboard

I'm about to start a game and I will be using spritekit but for the Menu screen and some other generic screens I can easily do it using storyboard. Is it a good practice to mix storyboard and Spritekit? Any downs of why I shouldn't do this? Or should i just stick to doing all scenes in spritekit?

Comment: I do everything in Sprite Kit, regardless of how complex it is. The reason is because I can make it work on OS X and iOS (and now Apple TV!) without needing to manage separate interface files. In fact I can actually do more then UIKit can do. For example I can do particle effects, physics and skeletal animations in my menus using my already existing code. Another possible benefit of this is that if you wish to port your game to a non-SpriteKit platform, you can  just swap out Sprite Kit for the equivalent engine (Assuming you designed your classes with this in mind).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I decided to use sprite kit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches are fine. If your menu and generic screens are not too complex maybe sticking to Spritekit would be a bit better in the long term.

See: [iOS 7 SpriteKit - Creating game menus/buttons (Scenes vs. more view controllers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320096/ios-7-spritekit-creating-game-menus-buttons-scenes-vs-more-view-controllers)

Comment: I decided to go with spritekit as my menu was not too complex. Thanks!