# Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 3

Tags: xcode

This compiles/works fine with *Xcode 5*, but causes a compile error with *Xcode 6 Beta 4*:

```
objc_msgSend(anItem.callback_object,
NSSelectorFromString(anItem.selector), dict);
```

This is a *3rd-party component*, so while I have the source code, it's not really my code and I'm hesitant to change it much (despite my personal opinion of 'wtf why are they using `objc_msgSend`??').

Image with possibly useful detail (error in error browser): [image]

Comment: The proper answer for this particular problem is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124512/kcorderedaccessorfix-objc-msgsend-too-many-arguments-to-function-call-expected

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer, and it's in Session 417 from 2014 WWDC "What's New in LLVM". If you find this code in a 3rd party library, such as Apsalar, updating to the latest version fixes it (probably because it's not distributed as a lib, ha). For an example of casting of these calls, see THObserversAndBinders library - I'm using it and noticed that the author updated the code, such as here:

https://github.com/th-in-gs/THObserversAndBinders/blob/master/THObserversAndBinders/THObserver.m

Comment: Very good answer. It fixed my Carousel issue. I just downloaded new FXImageView from github. And yes it works

Thanks @Alex the Ukranian

Answer (score 124):

If you think having to do this is annoying and pointless you can disable the check in the build settings by setting 'Enable strict checking of objc_msgSend Calls' to no

Comment: Pfiouuuu... Glad I found your answer!

Comment: I don't think this is an option if the error originates in a cocoa pod.

Comment: this is an option for a cocoapod, but you have to scroll to the "Pods" project in your workspace (and in my case, to the actual target pod)

Comment: nice answer, instant solution

Comment: not working for me on XCode 12.2. But @Sahil Kapoor solution works

Answer (score 26):

Just to spare watching a WWDC video, the answer is you need to strong type objc_msgSend for the compiler to build it:

```
typedef void (*send_type)(void*, SEL, void*);
send_type func = (send_type)objc_msgSend;
func(anItem.callback_object, NSSelectorFromString(anItem.selector), dict);
```

Here is another sample when calling instance methods directly, like this:

```
IMP methodInstance = [SomeClass instanceMethodForSelector:someSelector];
methodInstance(self, someSelector, someArgument);
```

Use strong type for methodInstance to make LLVM compiler happy:

```
typedef void (*send_type)(void*, SEL, void*);
send_type methodInstance = (send_type)[SomeClass instanceMethodForSelector:someSelector];
methodInstance(self, someSelector, someArgument);
```

Do not forget to set send_type's return and argument types according to your specific needs.

Comment: Swift sucks because it has no implicit type conversion. You must even cast each int to float/double. Now it seems Apple forces all the developers to do this to make swift more popular.

Comment: Good thing swift forces us to cast all those types, unlike C, or else we would easily end up with a load of math related bugs, and one would not so easily know where they came from. It is exactly because of implicit type conversion that, in C, you can so easily get into overflows, round off errors, etc. The list goes on and on and on. And they can be hard as hell to debug.

Answer (score 20):

This could also be caused by running `pod install` using Cocoapods `0.36.beta.2`. I have reported the issue to CocoaPods. "Workaround" by using CocoaPods `0.35`

Comment: Issue still present in Cocoapods 0.36.1 for me

Comment: To downgrade, use two commands: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` followed by `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.35.0`

Comment: issue still exists on 0.37.0 Had to revert back to 0.35.0 to make it work! Thanks @Maciej Swic

Comment: if you have multiple versions of cocoapods you should delete versions higher than 0.35.0 to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 15):

Setting `Enable strict checking of objc_msgSend Calls` to `NO`, solved my issue. Below is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Maciej Swic is right.This is caused in Pods after updating Cocoapods to 0.36.beta.2.
I found a simple workaround by type casting objc_msgSend:

```
id (*typed_msgSend)(id, SEL) = (void *)objc_msgSend;
id<MyProtocol> obJ = typed_msgSend(controller, @selector(myselector));
```

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error with QuickDialog. Following on to james_alvarez's answer but for **AppCode**, go to `Project Settings`, then click on `QuickDialog` under Project/Shared Settings, scroll down to ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND and enter NO for Debug and Release.

Answer (score 6):

You can also disable this with a post install hook:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: you can write in the bottom of your pod file

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <objc/message.h>

void foo(void *object) {
  typedef void (*send_type)(void *, SEL, int);
  send_type func = (send_type)objc_msgSend;
  func(object, sel_getUid("foo:"), 5);
}
```

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Following the accepted answer- to find the answer in the given codebase might be cumbersome for few, so here's the quick snap that should solve this problem.

I edited the code in `ActionSheetPicker` in my project, which was causing me the same problem, like this -

```
- (void)notifyTarget:(id)target didSucceedWithAction:(SEL)action origin:(id)origin {
    if ([target respondsToSelector:action]) {
        ((id (*)(id, SEL, NSDate *, id))objc_msgSend)(target, action, self.selectedDate, origin);
        return;
    } else if (nil != self.onActionSheetDone) {
        self.onActionSheetDone(self, self.selectedDate, origin);
        return;
    }

    NSAssert(NO, @"Invalid target/action ( %s / %s ) combination used for ActionSheetPicker", object_getClassName(target), (char *)action);
}
```

So look at the change that `objc_msgSend` portion has, compared to your current code.
The idea is to include the type of the parameters you are passing to `objc_msgSend`

Answer (score 0):

```
((void(*)(id,SEL,id))objc_msgSend)(target, sel, newValue);
```

Change the code like above, after Xcode 12, simply setting Setting Enable strict checking of objc_msgSend Calls to NO does not help. modify the (id,SEL,id) for your need, for example(id,SEL) for two arguments, etc

Answer (score -1):

This block of code reproduces the error:

```
- (void)reportSuccess:(void(^)(void))success
{
    success(what_is_this);
}
```

Guess where error is? Of course, *what_is_this* is not declared, but somehow magically it shows another error. In other words looks like if you have block, you can put any parameters when calling it, even non existent variables.