# KCOrderedAccessorFix objc_msgSend too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 2

Tags: ios, nsmutableorderedset

In Xcode 6 KCOrderedAccessorFix is producing errors on following line:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *primitive = objc_msgSend(_s, fastPrimitiveGetter)
```

How can I resolve it? Thanks,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change each objc_msgSend method call from

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *primitive = objc_msgSend(_s, fastPrimitiveGetter);
```

to

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *primitive = ((id (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(_s, fastPrimitiveGetter);
```

It's working perfectly for me.

Fix in my pull request:
https://github.com/aqibmumtaz/KCOrderedAccessorFix

Comment: its due to Warning "Enable strict checking of objc_msgSend calls" in XCode6 is enabled by default.

Comment: Here's my pull request https://github.com/aqibmumtaz/KCOrderedAccessorFix/commit/8f8b51ceaef32b72b27b04311309b5248f61758c

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the top of `kc_generateOrderedSetAccessorsForRelationship`:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet* (*action)(id, SEL) = (NSMutableOrderedSet* (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend;
```

And then change all calls to "`objc_msgSend`" to "`action`", like this:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *primitive = objc_msgSend(_s, fastPrimitiveGetter);
```

becomes:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *primitive = action(_s, fastPrimitiveGetter);
```

And everything I'm saying here is in [an open pull request written by somebody else](https://github.com/CFKevinRef/KCOrderedAccessorFix/pull/10/files).  :-)