# CocoaPods giving Too many arguments to function call error iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, xcode9-beta

I installed CocoaPods 1.3.1 to an already working project for installing the pods.On trying to run the code on xcode9 beta i am getting this error 'Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 2'.This is related to the CSMapper Framework which was used in the code.Anyone have idea on this?

Comment: CSMapper wasn't updated since March 2014. I'd suggest finding another library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24922913/too-many-arguments-to-function-call-expected-0-have-3