# Replicate (id) sender property in skspritenode button

Tags: ios, uibutton, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I noticed this discussion: [Setting up buttons in SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/setting-up-buttons-in-skscene) 
And decided to take a shot and use the SKSpriteButton class written by Graf, when creating a buttons in my game scrollers.

When the user taps on one of the buttons, the main object in the game should customized with that button's texture.

When I used UIButton it was very easy to determine which button was tapped (when all triggered the same function):

```
(IBAction)customizeMainObject: (id)sender;
```

Is there a way to replicate the same behavior with Sprite Buttons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up buttons in SKScene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/setting-up-buttons-in-skscene)

Answer (score 0):

You can make a subclass of SKSpriteNode that has a property called texture.  In TouchesBegan or TouchesEnded, check to see if any of the sprite buttons were touched.

ex.

```
if ([self.sprite containsPoint: location]) 
{               
    //set players texture = self.sprite.texture;
}
```