# Add button only in Code?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to add a button only in code. In the Xcode Simulator it works perfectly but not on my device  :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let image = UIImage(named: "playButton.png") as UIImage

    playButton   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100) // crash is here
    playButton.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/1.7)

    playButton.addTarget(self, action: "transition:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    playButton .setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.view?.addSubview(playButton)

}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work on your device? Saying it doesn't work is useless.

Comment: I can't launch it, I have a fatal error : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Where is the code you provide? is this code inside your viewController's `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: Yes it is. You can see my edit

Comment: shouldn't IBOutlet be written outside of it ? Also `self.frame` is indeed `self.view.bounds`, no?

Comment: Sorry, I edited again

Comment: There is no `self.frame` in a view controller. Please copy/paste your actual code instead of "editing" the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes no sense - if you are using @IBOutlet that means that your button is created in the storyboard, therefore you do NOT need to initialize it:

> ```
> let image = UIImage(named: "playButton.png") as UIImage
>
> playButton   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
> playButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100) // crash is here
> playButton.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.width/2, self.frame.height/1.7)
>
> playButton.addTarget(self, action: "transition:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
> playButton .setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
>
> self.view?.addSubview(playButton)
> ```

Remove all of the above code and set that up in the storyboard instead. @IBAction should be a separate method which is hooked up to your touchUpInside of your button in your storyboard.

Comment: Thank you! I removed @IBOutlet because I want my button only in code and it works like that.

Comment: Do you know how can I add the button on a scene ? When I add my code (without @IBOutlet) on my GameScene the button doesn't appear. Do you know why ?

Comment: Haox, if you are referring to SpriteKit scene I would check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/setting-up-buttons-in-skscene answer

Answer (score 2):

> In the Xcode Simulator it works perfectly but not on my device

That often means that you have a mismatch between your code and the actual name of a file. The MacOS X filesystem is normally *not* case sensitive, while the iOS file system *is* case sensitive. So, if your image file is named something like `PlayButton.png` or `playButton.PNG` but you specify `playButton.png`, it'll generally work on the simulator but not on the device.

**Make sure that the filenames in your code match the files in your project.**

Comment: Thanks! I know about case sensitivity but it's not the problem. I checked and it's ok

Answer (score 1):

"Unwrapping an optionnal value" seem to refer to the **!** next to your var declaration... What if you use **?** instead ?

From Swift doc

```
Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. 
Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.
```

Try this:

```
weak var playButton : UIButton?
```

and add ? after it when accessing it - like you do with `self.view?.addSubview` or locally force unwrapp it with **!** in methods where you know it has already been created

(I'm not sure though, still learning the language... :-)