# Xcode does not synthesize property with IOS 8 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a custom class that is working fine in iOS 7.

```
@interface SKBButtonNode : SKSpriteNode
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKTexture *normalTexture;
```

It works just fine on iOS7 and builds that are in appstore. Since iOS 8 my game crashes on launch. I localized the problem to:

```
[SKBButtonNode setNormalTexture:] unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb50b6c41d0'
```

What's up with this? If I synethize the property it works fine.

Comment: Could have something to do with the fact that a new property was introduced in iOS 8 with the same name...

Comment: Can you share some more code regarding the call to `setNormalTexture`? And are you using this whiten the SKBButtonNode class or are you calling this for an instance of SKBButtonNode in another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and the clue from borrrden in the comments to the original post helped me figure out how to resolve it. It looks like the name conflict with normalTexture in iOS8 was causing the crash.

I went through and renamed normalTexture in the button node class to myNormalTexture (.h and .m files) and that resolved this issue.

In the .h file:

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) SKTexture *myNormalTexture;

In the .m file make changes to:

- (instancetype)initWithTextureNormal:(SKTexture *)normal selected:(SKTexture *)selected disabled:(SKTexture *)disabled
- (void)setIsEnabled:(BOOL)isEnabled
- (void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)isSelected

Comment: I think I got this localized but did not respond to this post. New Xcode actually forces you to have both setter and getter if you customize any of them. Previously I had only custom getter, but not setter. Once I fixed this it worked