# How do I properly add a button to my scene using only code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Working off of other Stack Overflow answers, I have managed to come up with the code below:

(in my homescreen.m file)

```
 UIButton *GCButton;

 -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
     if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
         //add button
         [self addGameCenterButton];      
     }
     return self;
 }

 -(void)addGameCenterButton
 {
     GCButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 20, 30, 30)];
     [GCButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
     [GCButton setTitle: @"My Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [GCButton setTitleColor: [UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [GCButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
     [GCButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
     //adding action programatically
     [GCButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [self.view addSubview:GCButton];   
 }

 -(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
 {
     NSLog(@"you clicked on button %ld", (long)sender.tag);
 }
```

As of right now, I see nothing on my screen. Is there anything else I need to add in my .m or .h files to make the button work?

Comment: You are adding an action named `btnClicked:` but you defined it as `buttonClicked:`

Comment: thank you. I fixed that error but I still don't see a button on the screen. I'll edit my comment to take out the warning issue.

Comment: what is the type of your class (`self`) is this UIViewController?

Comment: @teamnorge Sorry for the dumb question but how do I check that?

Comment: in your header (.h) file what's  the super class after @interface, class name and then, just after `:`

Comment: @teamnorge it is SKScene. Should I change it to something else?

Comment: From which class your home screen is inherited ?

Comment: in GameViewController.m in the viewWillLayoutSubviews method I have this line of code:                                                        `HomeScreenGameScene * scene = [HomeScreenGameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments of your question, I'm assuming you are using `SpriteKit`. In a `GameScene`, unfortunately, you cannot use `UIButtons` normally.

To create buttons for your scene, please check the answers in the link below:
[Setting up buttons in SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/setting-up-buttons-in-skscene)

Comment: Oh, I did not know that you can't use buttons in spritekit. thanks anyway