# how to code UIbuttons/IBactions in touches methods for a Sprite kit game

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

In my previous app (single view application) i used touch down and touch up inside IBActions for buttons in my game. However in a SpriteKit game you have to completely create the scene and i am having a hard time coding my `touchesBegan` method.

Here is my basic movement method/function:

```
func heroMovementLeft () {

    hero.position = CGPointMake(hero.position.x - 0.5,hero.position.y);

}
```

here is my Left arrow node, i would like the HeroMovementLeft method to be called upon touching the LeftArrow

```
func LeftArrow () {

    let LeftArrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Left Arrow.png")
    LeftArrow.position = CGPointMake(30, 30)
    self.addChild(LeftArrow)
}
```

Here's where I am at right now for coding the `touchesBegan` method

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
       /* Called when a touch begins */

        for touch in touches {
        }
}
```

Do I create an if statement? Do I make touch a variable? What do I need to write in my touches began method so that my hero will move when left arrow is touched. I have looked all over online and cannot find an answer to this question, please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up buttons in SKScene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082202/setting-up-buttons-in-skscene)

Comment: There are few ways to go. The simplest would be to give the name to the node you want to move, and in the touchesBegan method use `nodeAtPoint `to see "if you are touching the right node"...

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 2 options to identify your sprites

1) make them global properties to your scene

```
   class YourScene: SKScene {

    var leftArrow: SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    }


    func leftArrow() {

        leftArrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Left Arrow.png")
        leftArrow.position = CGPointMake(30, 30)
        addChild(leftArrow)
   }
 }
```

than in touches began you can get the location like so

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
         let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
         let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

         if node == leftArrow {
             heroMovementLeft()
         }
      }
   }
```

Option 2 is to give your sprites names

```
 func leftArrow() {
    let leftArrow = SKSpriteNode(...)
    leftArrow.name = "LeftArrow"
    ...
 }
```

and than check for those names in the touches began method

```
  ....
  if node.name == "LeftArrow" {
     heroMovementLeft()
  }
```

As a side note you should start your properties or func with small letters and only start classes, structs and protocols with capital letters.

Comment: Thank you for the help @crachoveride777 I no longer get any error notifications but when i run the application in the simulator, the arrow does not display on the screen.I have tried multiple different CGpoints. Could this be because i did not execute the addChild(leftArrow) code in my override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) 
    }  ???

Comment: You will always have to call addChild(YourSprite) to add it to the scene.

Comment: I dont man this has nothing to do with the question you asked. Are you having other images like background sprites that might cover it. Try give the arrow a zPosition higher than your background sprite if you have one.

Comment: func LeftArrow() {
leftArrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "LeftArrow.png")
leftArrow.position = CGPointMake(30, 30)
addChild(leftArrow)
leftArrow.xScale = 300
eftArrow.yScale = 300
}override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = nodeAtPoint(location)

if node == leftArrow {
            heroMovementLeft()
I even changed the CGpoints and increased the size of the image incase the sprite was loading off but it still is not loading on the screen

Comment: where are you calling func LeftArrow() ?

Comment: you're right! I'm not, how and where should i call that method? do i just put   LeftArrow() under my override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */?

Comment: Well you need to call left arrow either in view did load or when you want it to show on screen.