# Call a method that returns a value from an NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, selector

I have a class method (+) that takes an argument of type `NSString`. What I want to do with that class method is to return information from another class method, there are many different class methods that return different things, I don't want to use a `switch or if-statement` but something like this:

```
return [self "ClassMethodName"];
```

I know how to do it with a `@selector()` but it seems like I cant use it in a class method. Is there another way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing it from a class method, `self` is the class object so you can do this:

```
+ (id)myClassMethod {
    return [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"ClassMethodName")];
}
```

If you're doing it from an instance method, you have to ask yourself for your class:

```
- (id)myInstanceMethod {
    return [self.class performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"ClassMethodName")];
}
```

Of course you can use `@selector(ClassMethodName)` if `ClassMethodName` is known at compile time, but I assume you don't actually know the selector name until runtime.

Note that Xcode doesn't know that `Class` objects are instances of `NSObject`, so it won't autocomplete `performSelector:` for you in these cases.

Comment: If `self` is a class, it will run the class method.

Comment: Oh wow, xcode didn*t suggest it when I typed it when the method was a class method, but it did when I changed it into an instance method... I had to just type the whole thing. darn you xcode.

Comment: Xcode doesn't know that `Class` is a subclass of `NSObject`.  It can be annoying.

Comment: Hm It give me a warning "PermformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown" Why does it give me that? I use the NSSelectorFromString() :S

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895530/77567) for two ways to suppress the warning.

Comment: clang warns you because it doesn't know for sure what method you're calling.  If the method returns an object that the caller is expected to release, clang (ARC) won't take care of releasing it and you'll leak memory.  So don't use `performSelector:` to call methods (like `copy` and `alloc`) that return an object with a +1 retain count.

Comment: Actually, `performSelector` is supposed to use with selector's of methods with return type of `void`. However, methods that return `int` or some pointer type won't won't crash if you call them via `performSelector` due to architecture specialties (for example, on x86 they will return value in `eax`, on armv7 maybe `r0`, i'm not sure), just leak an objects. The problem begins if you `performSelector` with selector with return type of some struct like CGSize or CGRect - the stack will be corrupted and you'll get your app crashd. For nonvoid methods use `NSInvocation` instead of `performSelector`

Comment: `performSelector:` is declared to return `id`, not `void`.  Furthermore, the [documentation of `performSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector:) says it returns “An object that is the result of the message”, not `void`.  It also says “For methods that return anything other than an object, use NSInvocation.”

Comment: Also, the implementation of `performSelector:` is [part of Apple's open source Objective-C runtime](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-551.1/runtime/NSObject.mm), and is essentially `return ((id(*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(self, sel);`.  Thus it is clearly intended to be used with messages that return `id`, not `void`.

Comment: @robmayoff: "Note that Xcode doesn't know that Class is a subclass of NSObject" There is no class named `Class`

Comment: @newacct True.  I have modified my answer.

Comment: @robmayoff: "Note that Xcode doesn't know that Class objects are instances of NSObject" That's only true for classes that inherit from `NSObject`.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually, since classes are objects themselves.

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"ClassMethodName");    

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
[self performSelector:selector];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

The pragma lines are needed to silence the compiler warning "PerformSelector may cause a leak because its selector is unknown" (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017281/performselector-may-cause-a-leak-because-its-selector-is-unknown) for details).